# Powershell: cannot call a method on a null-valued expression error

Tags: html, internet-explorer, powershell, form-submit, powershell-3.0

I am trying to login to a website via powershell.

**Here is PS code**

```
$username = "userhere" 
$password = "passhere"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$false
$ie.navigate("http://www.desistream.tv/en/login.shtml")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
$ie.document.getElementById("username").value= "$username"
$ie.document.getElementById("pass").value = "$password"
$ie.document.getElementById("loginform").submit()
start-sleep 20
$ie.Document.body | Out-File -FilePath c:\web.txt
```

**Here is Error I get when I run script.**

```
PS C:\Users\myname\Desktop> .\new.ps1
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\myname\Desktop\new.ps1:9 char:1
+ $ie.document.getElementById("loginform").submit()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

PS C:\Users\myname\Desktop> http://www.desistream.tv/en/index.shtml
```

Comment: I made `IE visible=true` and saw that was going on. It would fill out the username and password in the textbox but it is not clicking submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page doesn't have an element with the ID "loginform".

Comment: Thanks a lot `frmLogin`. Now I believe anything is possible. with programming.